# Printf style debugging via SWD

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m0

Is it possible to send arbitrary messages (as with printf()) via SWD for debugging?

Comment: Yes, but you need software on the device to stage messages or bytes (rather than writing them to the traditional UART), and software on the debug host to claim them.  Various open and proprietary implementations exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its called "Retargeting printf via ITM". its very easy to do with STM32.

EDIT:

You just need write a small "retarget.c" file. The key to this is using the "ITM_SendChar()" function.  Great tutorial here:
http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/arm/Retargetting_a_C_library_function/

I've personally have done this in the past and it works amazing in keil. Keil also has a bunch of tutorials on this. If you still have trouble, let me know

Comment: Googling "STM32 SemiHosting" gave me a bunch of solutions involing custom assembly programs and modifying the linker. Is this what you mean by "very easy" or am I looking at a wrong place?

Comment: Looking at the wrong place. Use the key word "retargeting" or "retarget"

Comment: See edits above in answer

Comment: But that method is using UART1 and not SWD for data transmission?

Comment: just realized that myself...see edit

Comment: Semihosting and ITM data trace are different technologies. A semihosted event halts the MCU and needs support from the debug tools to handle the semihosted operation and without debug tools attached, a semihosted event will permanently halt the MCU. An ITM event sends data to a port and does not cause the MCU to halt.